# Do mysql connection ids always increment, even if lower connections have been terminated?

Tags: mysql, macos, process, osx-mavericks

I'm setting up mysql and have noticed that whenever I connect, the connection id always increments. I thought that might mean the connection I thought had terminated didn't, but when I checked the number of connections using `sudo mysqladmin processlist`, it only listed the connection needed for that one command.

Normally I would just assume this was normal behavior and ignore it, but I had some problems uninstalling my old/messy installation from back when I didn't know what I was doing. Can anyone verify that this is normal? I tried checking the mysql manual [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_connection-id) but it wasn't specific enough to answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list all processes running on a MySQL instance state a query like this:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST
```

Each Connection will have a representation here (inactive ones with `Command` column = Sleep).

As to your question: No, Connection-ids will get re-used and will not increment forever. But you can't rely on the exact way they do so.

Comment: Great, thanks. The `SHOW PROCESSLIST` output looks the same as the `sudo mysqladmin processlist` output, and it's also only listing 1 connection, so I'm good.